# I have three ListViews, and on iOS scroll to top scrolls all of them up

Tags: flutter

I have the following:

```
IndexedStack(
  index: index,
  children: [
    Scaffold(
      body: ListView(),
    ),
    Scaffold(
      body: ListView(),
    ),
    Scaffold(
      body: ListView(),
    ),
  ],
)
```

However, on iOS, it seems that tapping the status bar to scroll to top scrolls all of these lists to the top.

Is there any way to make this behavior work correctly? I tried to add individual `controller: _scrollController` to each ListView, but that then didn't make the scroll to top work at all (tapping status bar did not scroll the list view).

Any way to make this work?

Update: Thanks to @vandad answer below, also with using key of `PageStorageKey` on each ListView/ScrollController/etc., it is possible to have the scroll to top functionality again on each individual view.

```
ListView(
  key: PageStorageKey<String>("GIVE A KEY"),
...
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that by setting the `primary: false` property of your other two `ListView` instances like this:

```dart
IndexedStack(
  index: index,
  children: [
    Scaffold(
      body: ListView(),
    ),
    Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        primary: false,
      ),
    ),
    Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        primary: false,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and programmatically updated the `primary` value based on the current `index` value, but that causes the scroll position to reset between each of those children views. Is there any way to preserve the scroll position?

For example, if child0 is currently viewed, the other children lists are `primary: false`, then if I go to view child2, the list on child0 is set to `primary: false` child2 is `primary: true`. However, if I go back to child0 I see it has scrolled to top.

Comment: What you could do to store the position manually is to set the `key` of your list views to PageStorageKey<String>('PUT THE NAME OF YOUR CHOICE HERE').

Comment: Thanks! That's amazing! I am now able to independently scroll to top on each of my views on iOS!!! Cheers!!

Comment: Great job. I'm glad this helped you and thank you for quick responses.